# How to find frequency that one "Order" will have two of the same parts

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm stumped on a problem. I'm willing to complete this in Access or Excel - whichever you all prefer!

I have two columns, order# and part#. Order # appears more than once if there was more than one part ordered in that order. A sample of potential data looks like this:

***Order #     |   Part #***

1234     |    A

1234     |    B

2344     |    C

3334     |    B

2431 | A

2431 | B

Sorry about the formatting! Basically, I'm trying to figure out the frequency that, for example, parts A and part B are ordered together - in this case 2 times. I'm not really interested about when a part is ordered individually, but rather in groups of 2, 3, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Excel, take a look at the `COUNTIFS` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a PivotTable because it will not only answer this question but maybe many others also:

[image: SO21717307 example]